# Assumption of independence of observations and data per year in linear regression

Tags: regression, assumptions, independence

I'm doing a linear regression model with data from 30 cities over 5 years (150 observations). However, by **using data from cities over time, am I violating the assumption of independence of observations?** Or does the fact that my sample has the same number of observations for each city makes the assumption respected?

P.S: I'm not interested in knowing the evolution of values ​​over time, just the relationship between the two variables.

Observations example:

```
City          Year         Value
New York      2010        $ 4,500 
New York      2011        $ 4,000
New York      2012        $ 4,300
New York      2013        $ 4,800
New York      2014        $ 4,100
Berlim        2010        $ 20,100
Berlim        2011        $ 19,500
Berlim        2012        $ 20,500
Berlim        2013        $ 19,900
Berlim        2014        $ 19,700
...
```

Comment: Hi @Igor. Could you indicate which regression assumption you mean specifically with a linked resource? The emboldened assumption, is not one I am familiar with. It seems to be a conflation of many different assumptions/statistical requirements.  Also, I am taking it that you're using a linear model suited to panel data?

Comment: @EB3112 this one https://www.statology.org/assumption-of-independence/

Comment: Fair. The problem with time series is that they're drawn with a natural order. They're serially dependent. So you basically need a weaker assumption of asymptotic independence/weak dependence.

Comment: @EB3112 So is it ok to use the data in this format in linear regression?

Comment: Hi @Igor. Linear regression is a very broad term. I would look up some panel data models. Regardless of the software you're using, have a look at this type of summary. https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-panel-data-regression-theoretics-and-implementation-with-python-4c84c5055cf8